# Should has or have be used in a [verb] while/during [verb] question?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, present-perfect

Should *has* or *have* be used in a [verb] while/during [verb] question? Example:

> "studying while working *HAVE/HAS* made me a tough person"

What should I use?

Comment: my first guess is "HAS" but i would like to know what you think :)

Comment: This question would be better on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"studying while working" is not plural, so *has* should be used.